# Keep me logged in forever without 'remember me' checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web

How can I keep my login session forever (even when I close the browser and **if I don't manage this site**)? Are any user scripts out there? If so, how can I implement it? Cookie? Loop of image loading?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can must cookie for BE or localstorage in FE. The third params mean remember user when they login success

```
var result = await _userService.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password,
                true, true);
```

And you need to put the config in startup to set expire time for cookie

```
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
    });
```

Hope that help.